# windows dns caching server: flush dns cache for single zone programatically

Tags: windows, domain-name-system

in bind9 I can use rndc flushname zone.tld from a shell.

In the Windows DNS mmc I can select the zone and delete it.

With dnscmd I can flush the whole cache, but I just need to flush a zone's cache every now and then.

Is it possible and how? TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DNSCmd.exe is used to display and change the properties of DNS servers, zones, and resource records. You can find detailed syntax [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc756116%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). 
As much as I would like to give proper reference and explanation for this, I found it by random googling, trial and error: cached lookups seem to be internally stored in Zone called ..Cache, and each cached zone is only a node under "..Cache", so the right switch to use is [/NodeDelete](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc756116%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_13):

```
dnscmd dnsserver.local /NodeDelete ..Cache whatever.com [/Tree] [/f]

 /tree    Specifies to delete all of the child records.
 /f       Executes the command without asking for confirmation.
```

Still, it would be cool if anyone could find "..cache" in MS official documentation.

Comment: A bit more explanation would make this a better answer.

Comment: There really isn't much to tell. /NodeDelete is well documented, and "..Cache" is ZoneName for all cached lookups.

Comment: Answers that consist of a blind command are not really "good" answers. The standard on Server Fault is that an answer should explain both the "How" and the ***"Why"***. That includes providing a few words summarizing the "well documented" flags.

Comment: OK, point taken.

Comment: Awesome! It works perfectly. Thanks for figuring this out.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid that programatically, you'll have to resort to `/clearcache`.

`dnscmd` doesn't have that functionality builtin, and there's nothing obvious in [the API spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682085(v=vs.85).aspx) that suggest such a operation is exposed

You can do it from the GUI, though I doubt that's any help
To view and remove cached entries from a Windows DNS Server:

1. Open the DNS Management Console (`dnsmgmt.msc`)
2. Go to the **View** menu, and select **Advanced**
3. Expand your DNS Server entry in the left pane
4. Expand **Cached Lookups**
5. To remove a cached record or an entire zone, simply right-click and choose "Delete"

For authoritative Servers, you can either refresh or reload zone data, depending on the source type.
For secondary name servers to refresh zone data from the master server:

```
dnscmd dns1.domain.tld /zonerefresh my.zone.domain.tld
```

For active directory integrated zones, reload the zone data from AD:

```
dnscmd dns1.domain.tld /zonereload my.zone.domain.tld
```

assuming that the fqdn of your dns server is `dns1.domain.tld.` and `my.zone.domain.tld.` is the fqdn of the zone

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am afraid my question regarded a caching DNS server, not an authoratitive one. I have edited the title of the question to reflect this.

Comment: by the way, I had already indicated that I could do it from the mmc but thanks anyway